# regex to concatenate two strings in C#

Tags: c#, regex, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate two sub strings from a input string using Regex
Example : Input string "ABTTPQR    00100300250000" and I want take first two characters "AB" and first 9 digits "001003002" and concatenate these two string to one "AB001003002"

Answer (score 2):

Much shorter variation using references:

```
Regex.Replace("ABTTPQR 00100300250000", @"^(\w{2})\w*\s(\d{9})\d+$", @"$1$2")
// = "AB001003002"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w{2})\w*\s(\d{9})\d*");
var matches = regex.Matches("ABTTPQR 00100300250000");
String output = matches[0].Groups[1].Value + matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
//AB001003002
```

Regex Explanation:

```
(\w{2})\w*\s(\d{9})\d*
```

The `(\w{2})` will match the first 2 chars, then it will look for more chars and a space `\w*\s` then it will match first 9 digits `(\d{9})` and then will look for more digits `\d*`.

The `()` captures the matches into groups which are accessed in c# like shown in code sample: `matches[0].Groups[1].Value` for group 1 (chars) and `matches[0].Groups[2].Value` for group 2 (digits)